# Объединить две колонки в третью

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица и в ней куча записей о местоположении людей. Надо взять колонки улица и дом и на их основе сделать апдейт и заполнить третью колонку в этой таблице - адрес. Те надо сделать апдейт каждой записи в БД. Самое очевидное, что приходит в голову, сгенерить огромный sql запрос другим запросом, который создаст кучу sql'ек с update, в которых будет указан id записи и собранное поле через concat_ws и после методично запихивать их в базу. Но может есть какой-то более адекватный способ для этого?

Comment: Зачем хранить колонку которую можно сгенерировать? Это нарушение 1NF.

Comment: Можно представление использовать.

Comment: Кто-то использует нормальную форму? Если будит работать быстрее, то можно и НУЖНО плюнуть на нормальную форму. Достаточно посмотреть хоть на Star Schema, в особенности хранение дней.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE test_table 
SET address = street ||" "|| home
```

Comment: Наверняка надо склеивать через пробел, просто автор вопроса об этом не подумал.

Comment: Можно было ещё where 1 приписать для наглядности, как мне кажется топик стартер не понимает, что sql это работа с _множествами_, а не с каждой строкой индивидуально.

Comment: @AK можно с помощью курсора сделать

Comment: Угу. И упомяните производительность курсора по сравнению с запросом.

Comment: @AK лучше в цикле update вызывать

Comment: @Илья-Королев Отметьте ответ решением, если вы им удовлетворены.

Comment: Надо добавить то, что если таблица огромная, то возникает проблемма: Всё это творится в одной транзакции, в которой лочится вся таблица. До окончания транцакции никто не будит иметь доступ к ни одной полной строки. Из-за этого надо по кластеру пробегаться и делать постепенно изменения в отдельных транзакциях.